# Reporting progress percentage from spawned processes

Tags: java, asynchronous, process, progress

My master process (implemented in Java) spawns a couple of processes asynchronously and I would like to report the progress of these processes. I would think the only way to do so, is to print certain information to the standard output or standard error stream and parse that text.

Is there a standard accepted way for doing this kind of thing, or am I on my own?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JMS` to send messages with some process ID and progress for example. Please read http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdq.html. I'm using `activemq` (http://activemq.apache.org/) as JMS broker.

There are plenty other ways to do it, but i think JMS is easy and popular one.

Comment: I would prefer not to have to install other applications just to make this (nice-to-have) feature work. Or would I embed activemq in my master process?

Comment: @WouterLievens http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html